# ESP8266/NodeMCU Android IDE

Tags: android, ide, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I just got NodeMCU dev kit for ESP8266, and I want to develop for it using my motox2013 Android phone. Any Ideas on how can I do that?

I know there is already an Android IDE for Arduino - Arduino Droid, but I couldn't get it to work with my NodeMCU.
There is an option there for costom hardware, but I get completely lost on how to use it.

Any ideas. on how to make this work?

Comment: `but I get completely lost on how to use it` show us at which step you are lost with a screenshot. It shouldn't be harder than selecting the right board type and click upload (nodemcu: ESP-12F module, 4MB flash, flash mode DIO, min 115200 baud)

Comment: There is no option for NodeMCU. I have to. install it manually somehow

Comment: need to write an app :) So you cannot do it with given IDE.

Comment: Maybe if i root my phone , I can use the linux shell version of Arduino?

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the nodeMCU board drivers. To do that you have to:

1. Go to your settings of the arduino IDE, by pressing `Strg + ,`.
2. Enter a URL so that the IDE gets access to the drivers. Enter the following URL: `http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json`, as below:

   [image: There you add the link]
3. Now open the Board Manager of the Arduino IDE and search for "esp".
4. There you get a result called "esp2866". Download the pack.
5. You now get new Boards to select.
6. Selest the NodeMCU 1.0(ESP-12E Module).

Now you can load up your scripts to the board...

Answer (score -1):

There is an [Android IDE for Arduino](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid2&hl=tr) but it seems that there is no support for installing additional board packages. So, I am sorry dude.

Comment: ArduinoDroid 5.0.x supports ESP8266 now

Answer (score -1):

As [@Maximilian Gerhard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5296568/maximilian-gerhardt)t already said, it's important, that you choose the right board.

We're assuming you want to use the Arduino IDE for this.

To be able to work with ESP8266 boards properly, you have to install the fitting boards manager. Go to [Boards manager for ESP8266](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino#installing-with-boards-manager). Do exactly as it says there.

When you have done so, you can go to *Tools* -> *Board:* and choose from a lot of different boards that have the ESP8266. For the *NodeMCU v3 ESP8266* you want to choose *NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)*.

[image: NodeMCU ESP8266]

Depending on your code, you only have to set the baud-rate you want to work with for your serial monitor and you're good to go!

There are also now a lot of example sketches that you can play with. An easy one to get started is found here:

[image: NodeMCU ESP8266 Example Sketch/Code]

As I wrote (and tried to explain) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46741984/8590406), please double check your pinouts when using sensors, actuators, UART or else. Especially with a NodeMCU, it gets confusing sometimes.

Comment: You would be right about a PC IDE, but I'm talking about Android (smartphone) IDE.