# WeMos (ESP8266) Function While

Tags: esp8266

My function while have a problem. When I comment this line doesn't have error in monitor serial, but, when I use all function show this error on monitor serial.

```
void windvelocity(){
speedwind = 0;
counter = 0;  
attachInterrupt(0, addcount, RISING);
unsigned long millis();       
long startTime = millis();
while(millis() < startTime + period) {
}
}
```

When I make upload this function to wemos, the Serial Monitor print this

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v09f0c112
~ld
```

Comment: How do you power your ESP8266?

Comment: This function is to see the velocity of anemometer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ain't a error message but a standard boot message. To properly answer your question we would need to know what board exactly you use, how you connected your parts (what pins, voltage, etc), what parts and of course the full code.

Please remember that the breakout boards for the esp8266 (for example the node mcu) are confusing sometimes. So always double check what pins you want to use and what pins you declared in your code.

[image: nodemcu esp8266 pinout]

[image: wemos d1 mini esp8266 pinout]

For example, if you want to have *D0* as the output for something, probably a LED, you will have to declare it as output.

```
pinMode(16, Output);           // set pin to output
```

Or when wanting to use it as input (for example for sensors) use

```
pinMode(16, Input);            // set pin to input
```

Why *16* when wanting to use *D0* you ask? Take a look at [this](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/variants/d1_mini/pins_arduino.h#L49-L61) for more information on how to refer to the pins as input or output . There you can see what pins to use.

Comment: Then, Any GPIO can be Input or Output? 
I think that my WeMos don't are working about this, because something I declare, but don't work about I need :/

Comment: Ok! Thanks I will be test! But any pin that are GPIO exept D0 (in wemos) I can declare input or output?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. You can read up on input methods [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins). This is important, because not every board can handle every input. It's important to know about resistors and how to use them. Let me know if it worked for you please!

Comment: I see and tested, but my problem that I studied are with  watchdog, because in the code have this loop. The pins I adjusted for my board. You have a sugestion about How it alter to don't stay this infinity loop, or how I insert a time to verify? Because as always I need to compile this, the watchdog undestand that my system locked :/

Comment: void windvelocity(){
speedwind = 0;
counter = 0;  
attachInterrupt(0, addcount, RISING);
unsigned long millis();       
long startTime = millis();
while(millis() < startTime + period) {
}
}

Comment: Please open up another question for this. It is not related to your original question. I will try to help out then, too!

Be sure to include the whole code and the type of board/ sensors you use. Good luck!

Comment: But there are in my original question, the diference that now I have more information about the problem in my function and your results

Comment: But there are in my original question, tur diferente that now I have more information about the problem in my function and your results

Answer (score 0):

Reset cause 2 means a reset by the reset pin trigger. Attach your anemometer to another pin and change your code to match the hardware layout.

Comment: I tested the code in Arduino and it is working, but in my Wemos don't work. 
Is it possible declare pins INPUT and OUTPUT? Because this declaration in esp8266 don't working

Comment: many pins on the wemos are special, only GPIO4+5 are completely free of side-effects